# How can I see the 4th ending to the game?

Tags: yesterday

The website for *Yesterday* boasts of 4 different endings. I quote from [the game's website](http://yesterday-game.com/):

> This is the starting point of a brand new adventure from Pendulo
>   Studios, which will drive you into a dark story full of twists and
>   turning points, and give you the chance to choose between 4 different
>   endings!

I've only seen three (listed below), and how to arrive at them all seemed very obvious. At the very end of the game, I was presented with a choice as to which character would act in the end:

[image]

**Cooper ending:**

> I choose Cooper and he tosses Henry in the pit. John, Cooper, and Pauline bury the temple and leave.

**John ending:**

> I choose John and he brands Henry's hand so that he'll be forever marked. John and Pauline bury the temple and leave.

**Henry ending:**

> I choose Henry and he convinces John to pull him up, then stabs John and pushes him into the pit. Henry buries the temple and drags off Pauline's body.

---

**Is there really a fourth ending, and if so, how do I achieve it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a walkthrough](http://www.gameboomers.com/wtcheats/pcYy/Yesterday/Yesterday.htm) explaining where the battery locations are.

When you arrive at the ruins of St. Fergus church at the end of the game, you need to look around for some batteries. Quoting from the walkthrough:

> The placement of the batteries is random and not shown by the crosshair-hotspot icon. There are 5 possible places that the batteries can be located: left and right edge of the rock ledge at bottom right; top of the mountain at left; top left edge of the mountain at right and dark wide path of the far mountain at center of screen. Take the batteries.

Then, to see the 4th ending, at the end of the game when you have a decision between three character, choose John. Then, instead of interacting with the knife, use the batteries on the Poet of Pain doll located at the top of a pillar on the left side of the screen.

Comment: An answer consisting of only a link can easily become broken if the linked site goes down or moves.  In this case, you linked to a link.  If possible, try to summarize the content relevant to the question.  Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Jessica I've edited the answer for you to include the relevant information from the walkthrough. For future answers, please try to summarize the relevant info from a link, as it makes the answer for more useful to other people.

Answer (score 2):

There's a 4th ending, you have to pick batteries in the scene of Scotland. But, their place is random ! If you picked this object, you can access to the 4th ending. :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Which scene in Scotland? What do I need to do with the batteries once I get them?